# EF Update DB Enable Migration Navigational Property Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using EF Migrations with MVC 5 - however I'm getting what I think/thought was/is a pretty common error, but the common solutions I've seen, I've already got:

*The property 'companyId' cannot be configured as a navigation property.The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type must implement ICollection where T is a valid entity type.*

From looking around my code looks correct, and worked prior to *enable-migrations* and *update-database* to see whether the test data in my system gets wiped before I put this change live. Within the ASN model I've added a string property of testAsn to see whether this gets added as a column to the database.

I am unsure if this error is relating to the ASN or the Contacts table/model, but they both have the same implementation.

Have I misunderstood regarding the use of navigational properties? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Models**

```
[Table("Company")]

    public class Company
    {
        [Key]
        public int companyId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Company name required.")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Telephone required.")]
        public string telephone { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Registration Number required.")]
        [StringLength(30)]
        public string regNumber { get; set; }
        // navigation properties  of the models that belong to the company
        public virtual IList<Asn> asns { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Contact> contacts { get; set; }
    }
[Table("Asn")]
    public class Asn
    {
        [Key]
        public int asnId { get; set; }
        public int companyId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("companyId")]
        // property I'm adding to test whether migrations is working
        public string testAsn { get; set; }
        // *******************************
        // as pointed out in the correct answer, the property below
        // this comment should be above testAsn
        // *******************************
        public virtual Company company { get; set; }
        [Required] // always has value
        public bool userBehalf { get; set; }
        [Required] // always has value
        public bool confirmAssignment { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Prefix required.")]
        public string prefixAnnounced { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Pending Ticket ID required.")]
        public string pendingTicket { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string comments { get; set; }
        public bool asNumType { get; set; }
        public string reason { get; set; }
    }
    [Table("Contact")]
    public class Contact
    {
        [Key]
        public int contactId { get; set; }
        public int companyId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("companyId")]
        public virtual Company company { get; set; }
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength=3)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Contact name required.")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Telephone required.")]
        [StringLength(30, MinimumLength=11)]
        public string telephone { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}" +
                            @"\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\" +
                            @".)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$",
                            ErrorMessage = "Email is not valid.")]
        public string email { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Contact type required.")]
        public string type { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Did you mean to put the `[ForeignKey("companyId")]` attribute on the `public string testAsn { get; set; }` property?

Comment: Omfg... If that's it...Just been reading it as it should have been, couldn't see the wood through the trees.

Comment: It's something that happens all too often for all of us. It's why I like [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) :)

Comment: Haha brilliant - not sure it'd go down too well in the office if I just sit.stand there chatting to an inanimate object.

Comment: Indeed! But rubber ducking is just a way of replacing an expensive developer with something cheap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misplaced the `ForeignKey` attribute in the `Asn` class. Instead of putting it on the `company` property, it's on the `testAsn` property.

Comment: So sorry - will accept when it lets me, ridiculous. Thank you so much.